# "unanswered" questions -> "my tags" - some questions missing and/or unclear sort order

Tags: support, specific-question, unanswered-questions

Hi,

So I'm trying to use "unanswered" -> "my tags" list on SO:

- https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered if you click on "unanswered", this gets "my tags" selected by default.
- https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged?tab=mytags if you click on "my tags" again.

The site says:

```
364
questions with no upvoted answers
in your tags
firefox dom xul xulrunner firefox-addon xpcom gecko google-wave mozilla firefox-extension
```

Listing several first questions from that list in order:

- [Difference in jQuery with XML namespace and xhr.responseXML between Opera and Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1601610/difference-in-jquery-with-xml-namespace-and-xhr-responsexml-between-opera-and-fir) 
  **modified Oct 21 at 15:25**
- ...
- [In what order do Firefox extensions get initialised?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1620422/in-what-order-do-firefox-extensions-get-initialised) **modified yesterday**

This question [First entry not easy to click issue in firefox,a bug?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1624036/first-entry-not-easy-to-click-issue-in-firefox-a-bug) is not on the list even though it's tagged "firefox" and was asked just now (no answers or votes).

**So what exactly is the "my tags" subtab of the "unanswered" tab is supposed to list and in what order?**

(FWIW, didn't find this in the "official" faq, nor searching here)

Comment: BTW, I'd expect that list to list all the questions with one of my tags in the last modified (e.g. edited, commented, or replied-to) order or asked order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is sorted by votes. So I guess it is in that list, but because it has no votes yet, you have to flip through the pages.

Comment: Aha (by question-votes)! Thanks. Seems obvious in hindsight... Anyway, do you know what order is it sorted in the groups having the same score? Seems to be by the text in "modified", so is it "question-last-modified date"?

Comment: Atypical for Jeff to *not* sort posts with the same votes randomly. But it looks like they are sorted by modified date as you've assumed.

Comment: The question was that I'm not 100% sure what "Modified" refers to. Does it include replies and comments or just the question edits?

Comment: Includes question edits and replies, no comments.

Comment: Thanks again! (yeah, a comment requires at least 15 characters, so I'll keep typing and typing and typing...)

Answer (score 1):

Confirmed, I added the firefox and firefox-addon tags to my list and got Question number 1620422 but not 1624036

One thing though, there are no questions newer than 18 hours old in my list but I know there are a few that are unanswered. So could it be that there is a time limit on when questions enter this list.

Comment: Time limit would be fine if I at least knew the way the list was sorted. Right now I can only assume it's sorted randomly, which means that in order to track it, you have to scan it all.